# Max height and width for an img, with negative margins/overflowing instead of scaling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a set of images, each with slightly different sizes. I want to be able to create `img` elements that have a specific max size, but instead of images being rescaled when the image exceeds the max size, the image instead "overflows" out of its container, as if it had negative margins. For instance, if I specify a max width of 10px, but have an image that is 12px in width, instead of rescaling the image to 10px it would stick out 1px on each side, overlapping neighbouring elements. Is this possible with pure CSS?

Comment: Is this happening across all browsers? I know some browsers don't support max-width

Answer (score 0):

[image]Em, may be I did't got it but if apply .fix-seze to div and image, image doesn't overflow.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fix-size {
            max-width: 50px;
            max-height: 50px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fix-size">
        <img class="fix-size" src="test.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="fix-size">
        <img class="fix-size" src="test2.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="fix-size">
        <img class="fix-size" src="test3.png" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not providing your container and image classes I'm not sure what's wrong with your current classes, but here's what you can do:

Wrap your image in a container where you will define max width and then add a class that will make your image's width 100% of that container. Ie. I'm using a 1000 x 1000 image.

UPDATE: You could add the property `overflow: hidden;` to your container class just to make sure nothing overlaps.

```css
.img__container {
  max-width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img__container">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.placehold.it/1000x1000">
</div>
```